# League of Legends - Skill/Cooldown keys

Tags: league-of-legends

Occasionally in games, you'll get individuals using the new feature that lets you click skills and automatically put them up with the timer in chat.

Does anyone know how to do this, is it a third party app or is it built in?

Example of such in chat:

> SteraksExchange(Ryze): Flash - 32s
>   Othersummoner(Sona): R- 10s
>   TSM DoubleRift(Lucian): Q - 2s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is built in, it was a feature with the latest patch (6.14). Simply use  <kbd>alt</kbd> + click on the ability, summoner spell, health/mana pool, or click on the objective timer to send a message with the cooldown on the ability, percentage of mana/health, or jungle respawn timer. See [here](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-614-notes#patch-cooldown-pings) for the patch notes on it.

Comment: You can use your ping key as well (mine is G) and instead of clicking on the map click on your spell/ability/etc.  Be sure to press the key first though as I have accidentally used my ult by just clicking it once :S

Comment: yea but did anyone notice that amazing pun "Steraks Exchange". :D

Answer (score 0):

It is a built in function. By default, you press and hold the Alt key, then click on the skill (or Baron/dragon) to show the cooldown.

Comment: For jungle timers you don't to hold alt. This was to prevent alt+tabbing out of the game.